Unable to authenticate Jira via API
When I do this in postman everything work perfectly

I'm trying to do same things in a Spring Boot project, but I'm getting a  401 error.
Here is my Authorization code
public class RestClient {

    private String server = "company.com";
    private RestTemplate rest;
    private HttpHeaders headers;
    private HttpStatusCode status;

    public RestClient() {

        this.rest = new RestTemplate();
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("Accept", "*/*");
        //headers.add("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
        headers.add("Connection","keep-alive");


        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode("user:password".getBytes()));
        System.out.println(basicAuth);

        headers.add("Authorization", basicAuth);

    }

   ** public String get(String uri) {

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = rest.exchange(server + uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
        this.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCode());

        System.out.println(requestEntity.getBody());
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }**

 

    public HttpStatusCode getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(HttpStatusCode status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    public String getJiraStatus(String jirdID) throws JSONException {
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient();

        String status = restClient.get("/rest/api/2/issue/" + jirdID + "?fields=status");
        System.out.println("status jira:  "+status);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(status);

        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("fields");

        JSONObject object2 = (JSONObject) object.get("status");

        String object3 = object2.getString("name");

        System.out.println("STATUS JIRA: ------- "+object3);

        return object3;
    }


}

ERROR MESSAGE

I've already tried headers.add("Authorization", "Basic  dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==") instead of  headers.add("Authorization", basicAuth); but unfortunately it doesn't work either.
